# How create a banner block with a name using a command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I can name a banner item with a give command:

```
give @p minecraft:banner 1 1 {display:{Name:"BlueFlag"}}
```

But I can't add a name with a command like this:

```
/setblock -263 99 69 minecraft:standing_banner 0 0 <NBT Tag>
```

I've tried every possible NBT Tag I can think of/find. Does anyone know if naming banner blocks is impossible for some reason?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is impossible. Placed banners are blocks (well, tile-entities), and blocks cannot have names that appear above them, only entities.

A workaround perhaps could be to summon an invisible ArmorStand or WitherSkull with the name you want, and have that on the banner so that it appears as if the banner has a name. Try this command:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Banner",Invisible:1b,CustomNameVisible:1b}
```

The minecraft wiki has pages on NBT data, including that of tile entities. Rather than guessing, it's a good guide to check what tags an entity/tile-entity has.

**Entities and Tile-Entities:**
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format

**Players and Items:**
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_Format

Comment: This tile-entity vs. item thing is what I'm confused about. Aren't most blocks both items and tiles? Items when in hand, and blocks when placed?

Comment: @Dyldo42 If items are dropped then they're entities, otherwise they're data in an inventory. An item can place a tile-entity (chest, furnace), a block (stone, wood), or an entity (spawn egg, boat). What **items** are isn't really relevant to the explanation, just the difference between entities and blocks.